# Word: Display the Navigation for the Headingds in a TableCell

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ms-word, telerik, openxml

I generate an SSRS report from C# code, and, as the report is a long one, users should use the Navigation pane in order to navigate trough the document.

I generate the report via SSRS, as byte array, and then try to update the headings paragraphs in order to make appear items the Navigation pane...

However, if the manual report allows it, by using "Heading1", "Heading2" styles, these one, once in a table cell, does not diplay in the Navigate panel.

[image]

The text in TableCell is the only way a SSRS report works. There is no way to put text direclty in a Section...

Is there a way, by code, to display the table cell headings? or split the table, and insert, say, instead of the TableCell with Heading1 a Section with the Paragraph having Heading1 style?

The only fields displays in the navigate panel are the added directly in a Section, by code

```
string heading1StyleId = BuiltInStyleNames.GetHeadingStyleIdByIndex(1);
string heading2StyleId = BuiltInStyleNames.GetHeadingStyleIdByIndex(2);
string heading3StyleId = BuiltInStyleNames.GetHeadingStyleIdByIndex(3);

document.StyleRepository.AddBuiltInStyle(heading1StyleId);
document.StyleRepository.AddBuiltInStyle(heading2StyleId);
document.StyleRepository.AddBuiltInStyle(heading3StyleId);


TParagraph paragraph = new(document) { StyleId = heading1StyleId };
TParagraph paragraph2 = new(document) { StyleId = heading2StyleId };
TParagraph paragraph3 = new(document) { StyleId = heading3StyleId };

paragraph.Inlines.AddRun(myText);
paragraph2.Inlines.AddRun(myText + "2");
paragraph3.Inlines.AddRun(myText + "3");

Section section = new Section(document);
section.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
section.Blocks.Add(paragraph2);
section.Blocks.Add(paragraph3);
```

Comment: See my article: Headings that do not show up in the Navigation Pane or Table of Contents https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd It is the nature of Word  and the Navigation Pane that headings inside tables do not show up in the Navigation Pane. Period.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon "nature of Word", seems like "God want it"... is there a more technical explanation and a workaround on how to solve it? Usually we post questions on SO to find solutions

Comment: This is the way Word is built. There is no real documentation on how the Navigation Pane functions. It is not accessible by vba but only responds to certain text in a certain format and not to text in textboxes or tables. There is no known workaronud. You could, I suppose, try constructing your own analog of the Navigation Pane as a TOC inside a textbox or frame in the header and have that appear on every page. Being a TOC field, it will pick up those headings in modern versions of Word. However, that will not really give a clickable hyperlink until converted to pdf.

Comment: If you want to go the extra step of putting it in pdf format after Word, you can have an analog of the Navigation Pane. Here are two temporary links, one to the Word document https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww6oqlyqpz27r25/deleteme%20Navigation%20Pane%20analog.docx?dl=0 and the second to the pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/0p22n9irecvxcmg/deleteme%20Navigation%20Pane%20analog.pdf?dl=0 from that document.